# How can I find out what a device is by its UUID?

Tags: backup, error, uuid

I've been having trouble with my Time Machine lately and I'm trying to figure out what the culprit is by examining the log. I've seen numerous "yellow warning" messages like this:

```
failed to get LastCloudBackupDate (0xE8000008) for device 00008110-001A15011A62401E (0x7fd2411602b0)
```

(this is being reported by the AMPDevicesAgent, FYI)

I know how to use the `diskutil` command to get UUIDs for volumes, but I'm not sure where the device ID mentioned in this error message comes from.

Is there a way to figure out what this device ID is so I can see if it is something I can resolve? Any ideas what this might be as well? I do see a lot of UNIX error 17s near it as well for what that is worth...